# Struts 1.3 ActionErrors access

Tags: struts, request

In my ActionForm i have the validate method:

```
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request){

    ActionErrors errorList = new ActionErrors();
    errorList.add("myError", new ActionMessage("this is my error"));
    return errorList;
}
```

Then the flow will be returned to the page form.jsp.

I want to access that error from my form.jsp page but using JSTL's EL and not **html:error**
tag.
I know that errorList is stored as an Attribute on the requests scope but I need the exact name of the attribute. Can you tell under what name is that errorList stored on the request?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ERROR_KEY in Globals](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/Globals.html#ERROR_KEY); its value is `"org.apache.struts.action.ERROR"`.

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to use this with JSTL?

Comment: @TGM Not sure what you mean; it's a regular request attribute key--all regular JSTL stuff works with it. I'm not sure I'd bother not using the Struts tags for Struts-specific functionality, though.

Comment: It is more of a theoretical problem for me. I don't really understand which is the exact Attribute name that I should use to access the "myError" content. The ERROR_KEY and ERROR are constants and, from what I know, can't be accessed with JSTL.

Comment: @TGM The *value* is the string `"org.apache.struts.action.ERROR"`, that is the request attribute's key.