# How to access ActionErrors programmatically?

Tags: struts, struts-1

I know how to create ActionErrors, add some messages and display the messages in the JSP page. 
I think ActionError is like a list of error message. Here is the method to threat error that my system uses:

### My Action

```xml
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
errors.add("customerId", new ActionError("error.customerId.required"));
this.saveErrors(request, errors);
```

### my current JSP

```xml
<html:errors />
```

suppose i want to create ArrayList (in Java) of the error message in the JSP page. How to do this ***without change anything in in my Action***.

### my proposed JSP

```xml
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<%
    ArrayList<String> errMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
    //foreach (ActionErrors.message as message){
    //    errMessage.add(message);
    //}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts 1.3 ActionErrors access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242712/struts-1-3-actionerrors-access)

Comment: thanks for comment, i am still newbie to this. could you give me more detail the answer to my code above? (convert to array list)

Comment: And why you need to convert to `java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: @PaulVargas we have a project which communicate between the servlet and android device. i will put the ArrayList into a class and then serialize and finaly print the serialized code. So my device read the code and deserialized. Actually my problem was solved by ugly method. it was print the message normally and cut the html to get the error list.
and also the system is very huge so we have no time to do this in the Action which each error was defined, so i wrote "without change anything in in my Action.

Comment: `ActionErrors` shouldn't be used in Struts 1.3.x. Rather use `ActionMessages` and save it on `saveErrors()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Action

If you save the errors in the `request` scope, e.g.:

```java
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
errors.add("usr", new ActionMessage("User required", false));
errors.add("pwd", new ActionMessage("errors.invalid", "Password"));
saveErrors(request, errors);
```

#### JSP

You can get the errors in your JSP in order to populate your array list in the following way:

```html
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.struts.Globals"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources"%>
<%
ArrayList<String> errMessage = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
ActionErrors errors = (ActionErrors) request.getAttribute(Globals.ERROR_KEY);
Iterator<ActionMessage> iterator = errors.get();
MessageResources resources = (MessageResources) request.getAttribute(Globals.MESSAGES_KEY);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ActionMessage error = iterator.next();
    if (error.isResource()) {
        errMessage.add(resources.getMessage(error.getKey(), error.getValues()));
    } else {
        errMessage.add(error.getKey());
    }
}
%>
```

<sub>**NOTE**: This code example use Struts 1.3.10.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I looking for.